# Listing Books nicely - a tour through a webapp

Tags: java, object-oriented, jpa

In this exercise, I do not want to use any container such as Spring or Glassfish. I am deploying my application to Tomcat. I only use JPA. What I want to achieve is to follow best practices and OOP concepts correctly, and a good separation of concerns and layering.

I have a database table like this:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE book;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+
| isbn        | varchar(13)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |
| name        | varchar(64)  | NO   | UNI | NULL    |
| publishDate | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |
| price       | decimal(8,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |
| publisher   | varchar(6)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+
```

and here is my `Entity`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {

    @Id
    private String isbn;

    @Basic
    private String name;

    @Basic
    private Date publishDate;

    @Basic
    private double price;

    @Basic
    private String publisher;

    // Getters, Setters...
```

This is my `PersistenceUtil` class:

```
package biz.tugay.books10Aug.dao;
/* User: koray@tugay.biz Date: 10/08/15 Time: 22:22 */

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class PersistenceUtil {

    private static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    public static void initalizeEntityManagerFactory() {
        if (entityManagerFactory == null || !entityManagerFactory.isOpen()) {
            entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("bookshop");
        }
    }

    public static EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
        return entityManagerFactory;
    }

    public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        if (entityManagerFactory == null || !entityManagerFactory.isOpen()) {
            initalizeEntityManagerFactory();
        }
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        return entityManager;
    }

    public static void closeEntityManagerFactory() {
        entityManagerFactory.close();
    }

}
```

and in my web application I have a `ContextListener`:

```
package biz.tugay.books10Aug.web;
/* User: koray@tugay.biz Date: 10/08/15 Time: 22:24 */

import biz.tugay.books10Aug.dao.PersistenceUtil;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;

@WebListener
public class BookShopServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        PersistenceUtil.initalizeEntityManagerFactory();
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        PersistenceUtil.closeEntityManagerFactory();
    }

}
```

**#1 Is this the right way to initialise Persistence Context? Or should this be responsibility of DAO / Service classes?**

My DAO Layer:

```
package biz.tugay.books10Aug.dao;
/* User: koray@tugay.biz Date: 10/08/15 Time: 22:50 */

import biz.tugay.books10Aug.model.Book;

public interface BookDao {
    public void persist(Book book);
    public Book getWithIsbn(String isbn);
}
```

and the implementation:

```
package biz.tugay.books10Aug.dao;
/* User: koray@tugay.biz Date: 10/08/15 Time: 22:54 */

import biz.tugay.books10Aug.model.Book;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

public class BookDaoImpl implements BookDao {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public BookDaoImpl(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void persist(Book book) {
        entityManager.persist(book);
    }

    @Override
    public Book getWithIsbn(String isbn) {
        Book book = entityManager.find(Book.class, isbn);
        return book;
    }

}
```

**#2 Is it ok that the DAO Layer requires an `EntityManager` and assumes that its transaction has already begun? Should it be the DAOs responsibility to obtain the `EntityManager` and/or begin/commit transaction?**

Here is my Service Layer:

```
package biz.tugay.books10Aug.service;
/* User: koray@tugay.biz Date: 11/08/15 Time: 00:12 */

import biz.tugay.books10Aug.model.Book;

import java.util.Date;

public interface BookService {

    public void createBook(String isbn, String name, Date publishDate, double price, String publisher);

    public Book getWithIsbn(String isbn);

}
```

and the implementation:

```
package biz.tugay.books10Aug.service;
/* User: koray@tugay.biz Date: 11/08/15 Time: 00:12 */

import biz.tugay.books10Aug.dao.BookDao;
import biz.tugay.books10Aug.dao.BookDaoImpl;
import biz.tugay.books10Aug.dao.PersistenceUtil;
import biz.tugay.books10Aug.model.Book;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import java.util.Date;

public class BookServiceImpl implements BookService {

    private BookDao bookDao;
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public BookServiceImpl() {
        EntityManager entityManager = PersistenceUtil.getEntityManager();
        bookDao = new BookDaoImpl(entityManager);
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void createBook(String isbn, String name, Date publishDate, double price, String publisher) {
        Book book = new Book();
        book.setIsbn(isbn);
        book.setName(name);
        book.setPublishDate(publishDate);
        book.setPrice(price);
        book.setPublisher(publisher);
        EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();
        bookDao.persist(book);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public Book getWithIsbn(String isbn) {
        EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();
        Book withIsbn = bookDao.getWithIsbn(isbn);
        transaction.commit();
        return withIsbn;
    }

}
```

**#3 Again, I have the same questions on my mind. Is this class a mess like this? It does not have any dependencies, it obtains its `EntityManager` from the `PersistenceUtil` class in the Constructor. Is this ok? How about the `entityManager` field and starting / committing transactions which surrounds DAO calls?**

And finally I have a view like this:

```
<form action="<c:url value="/book"/>" method="post">
    <label for="isbn">
        isbn:
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="isbn" id="isbn"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

and a Servlet:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/book")
public class BookServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        BookService bookService = new BookServiceImpl();
        String isbn = req.getParameter("isbn");
        Book withIsbn = bookService.getWithIsbn(isbn);
        req.setAttribute("book", withIsbn);
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/isbn.jsp").forward(req,resp);
    }
}
```

**#4 Is it ok that the Servlet initialises a `Service` object for each call? Or should it have a private static Service object?(I think not, but I am not sure thus asking..)**

As I said, (just for learning purposes) I want to make such a basic web app which is maintainable and which follows OOP principles, without using any other frameworks such as Spring.

Comment: You know, whether or not you use an IoC container shouldn't affect the architecture of the code. I find it odd that you're coupling types with that `PersistenceUtil` class, which looks like a static service locator. Would you inject the IoC container as a dependency if you were using one? SOLID OOP code isn't about the IoC container, it's about specialized objects, high cohesion and low coupling. Depending on abstractions and constructor-injecting them doesn't require a DI framework, and not using a DI framework shouldn't increase coupling at all - in fact, it should have 0 effect on the code.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Thank you for your comment. My question is, when you use a container, it injects the dependencies. Here, who should be responsible for providing the dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Doing work in constructor

This

```
public BookServiceImpl() {
    EntityManager entityManager = PersistenceUtil.getEntityManager();
    bookDao = new BookDaoImpl(entityManager);
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}
```

should be

```
public BookServiceImpl(EntityManager entityManager, BookDao bookDao) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
    this.bookDao = bookDao;
}
```

move the code to the calling site. Then extract the moved code to a factory method, as you will use it multiple times. Voila, no mess in constructor, no unnecessary dependency to an evil singleton.

```
// call site
BookService bookService = getBookService();
bookService.getWithIsbn(...)

// factory method
public BookService getBookService() {
     EntityManager entityManager = PersistenceUtil.getEntityManager();
     BookDao bookDao = new BookDaoImpl(entityManager);
     return new BookServiceImpl(entityManager, bookDao);
}
```

This method would be in the servlet at first. You can move this to a factory class, so that you can call it in multiple servlets using this service.

```
public class BookServiceFactory {

    public BookService create() {
       // same method just cut and paste.
    }
}
```

So that `getBookService` would now read;

```
// factory method
public BookService getBookService() {
     return new BookServiceFactory().create();
}
```

### Transaction Management

Transaction should be rollback in case of an exception.

`EntityManager` should be closed in order for entities to be detached. (As far as I can remember. I don't do entity life-cycle management by hand, so consult the documentation for details.)

### Noise

Use a version control system, such as git, if you aren't already; and remove these unnecessary comments.

```
/* User: koray@tugay.biz Date: 10/08/15 Time: 22:22 */
```

> Is it ok that the Servlet initialises a Service object for each call?

Depends. Try it both ways and see if memory consumption and response times change.

However since there is a choice here, this means extract the code to a method. So that when you need to change your decision, you will change the code in one place.

The end result should look like this:

```
    BookService bookService = getBookService();
```

> Or should it have a private static Service object?(I think not, but I
>   am not sure thus asking..)

Avoid `static` as much as possible. They introduce unnecessary dependencies. And cause hard to debug memory leaks.

You can change it to use the singleton scope like this:

```
public BookService getBookService() {
     return (BookService)getServletContext().getAttribute("books10Aug.BookService");
}
```

You should set the attribute during servlet context initialization. There would then be one `BookService` per (deployed) application.

Comment: Can you show the Factory class as well? But then Servlet will be responsible for calling the Factory, no?